# How to fix this MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm trying to get this trigger to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Transaction_insert BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
FOR EACH ROW WHERE Number = NEW.AccountNumber 
IF Account.CreditBalance + NEW.Amount < Account.CreditLimit THEN
UPDATE Account SET CreditBalance = CreditBalance + NEW.Amount where Number = NEW.AccountNumber;
ELSE
SET NEW.Valid = 0
END IF;
```

This is the error I get from myPHPAdmin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

This is what I think you want, assuming that `Account` to `Transaction` is a 1:N relationship keyed on `Number`/`AccountNumber`:

```
DELIMITER //

-- Assumptions:
--   1. Transaction.AccountNumber is F.K. REFERENCES Account(Number)
--   2. Account.Number is UNIQUE
--
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bi_transaction BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Adjust account balance (if permitted)
  --
  UPDATE Account
     SET CreditBalance = CreditBalance + NEW.Amount
   WHERE Number = NEW.AccountNumber
         AND
         (CreditBalance + NEW.Amount) < CreditLimit;

  -- Was the adjustment valid/permitted?
  --
  SET NEW.Valid = (ROW_COUNT() = 1);
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

That trigger will attempt to UPDATE the proper `Account` for any given `Transaction` if the `CreditLimit` permits.  The `Valid` field will be set to 1 if the UPDATE succeeded, and 0 if it did not.

### Original Answer

MySQL triggers do not support trigger-level WHERE clauses.  Move the Number/NEW.AccountNumber check inside the trigger body.

Comment: Where should I put it? I moved it right after the IF statement and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your IF needs to be a full SELECT to reference another table (`Account`)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `Account` A
            WHERE A.CreditBalance + NEW.Amount < A.CreditLimit AND 
                   A.Number = NEW.AccountNumber) THEN
   UPDATE ...
```

Edit: this was on your 2nd duplicate answer

In this case, remove the WHERE after FOR EACH ROW

Comment: That's true, but that's not the OP's immediate syntax error.  It's the trigger-level WHERE that's tripping him up.

Comment: @pilcrow: I originally answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8397805/27535 where it's slightly different

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't think IF EXISTS is grammatical. I have seen examples of WHERE EXISTS but not IF EXISTS.

Comment: @z-buffer: then it is a limitation of MySQL. `IF EXISTS` is valid SQL syntax in other engines

Comment: @z-buffer: I'll have MySQL in front of me on Friday to test solutions