# How to fix this IF-ELSE-THEN statement in a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix this MySQL trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397172/how-to-fix-this-mysql-trigger)

```
CREATE TRIGGER Transaction_insert BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
FOR EACH ROW
IF Account.CreditBalance + NEW.Amount < Account.CreditLimit WHERE Number = NEW.AccountNumber THEN
UPDATE Account SET CreditBalance = CreditBalance + NEW.Amount where Number = NEW.AccountNumber;
ELSE
SET NEW.Valid = 0
END IF;
```

I get this error message from phpMyAdmin.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper syntax for the If statement.

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

You can't have the `Where` clause in that spot!